# Must be one of: android.widget.Toast.LENGTH_SHORT, android.widget.Toast.LENGTH_LONG less... (Ctrl+F1)

Tags: android

I am using `toast` message to display text for users. From past few days i am getting this error . when i inspected my code then it showed incorrect constants error in every class. Can anyone show me what I did wrong.

```
Toast.makeText(AddAlbumActivity.this, R.string.all_fields_mandatory, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
```

Answer (score 1):

```
Toast.makeText(AddAlbumActivity.this, getString(R.string.all_fields_mandatory), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
```

Your second parameter is a *resource id* and should be an *string*.

You can get it with getString if you are on an activity, elsewhere you can use getString from a context.

Comment: That's not true, with an string resource works as well

Comment: I see, I've always passed the string. Then I see no mistake at all. Maybe, check you are importing the right Toast class from android.widget and not another one.

Comment: The one I've said android.widget.Toast is the correct one. But anybody can create other Toast classes on another packages, that's why I've proposed to check it's this one the imported class.

Comment: import android.widget.Toast this is same

Comment: And are you absolutely sure the bug is on this line? Maybe showing a stacktrace could help.